# How can I programmatically update the helperText of a Material UI TextField based on the value of the TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to update a Material UI TextField's helperText based on the value of the TextField. Here's what I have:

```
const defaultScores = {
  STR: 10,
  DEX: 10,
  CON: 10,
  INT: 10,
  WIS: 10,
  CHA: 10
}
const [abilityScores, setAbilityScores] = React.useState(defaultScores);
const handleScoreChange = (event) => {
const { ability, score } = event.target;
setAbilityScores({
  ...abilityScores,
  [ability]: score,
});
const modifier = (abilityScores.STR - 10) / 2;
document.getElementById("str-input").setAttribute("helperText", modifier >= 0 ? "+" + modifier : "-" + modifier);
};           
<TextField id="str-input" name="str" label="STR" defaultValue={abilityScores.STR} fullWidth margin="dense" type="number" variant="standard" onChange={handleScoreChange} />
```

When I update the value of the TextField, nothing happens with the helperText. Granted this is my first time using Material UI so I'm unfamiliar. Also I don't normally touch JS so I'm out of my element here in the first place. If more info is necessary then please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use the `helperText` property of `TextField`? You can see more details at [text-field api page](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/)

Comment: @HenriqueHoltz I'm trying to populate the field programmatically. I need it to change as the value changes, not set it once and be done.

Comment: It's possible as I said. You can add the property in your `TextField`, something like  `helperText={modifier >= 0 ? "+" + modifier : "-" + modifier}` and remove the line `document.getElementById...`, that it'll works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `document.getElementById` is suitable for React, it's more of something for vanilla JS.

Also not so sure of your `handleScoreChange` function, but it's likely not going to work since `event.target` only has `.value` that outputs the text value when new characters are typed. So usually the implementation for text change is going to be:

```js
const handleScoreChange = (event) => setAbilityScores(event.target.value);
```

In react, you can handle this with `useMemo` hooks, where you'll define `helperText` with `useMemo` and make `modifier` as the dependencies such that the value will change when the value of `modifier` change.

```js
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const FunctionalComponent = () => {
   const defaultScores = {
     STR: 10,
     DEX: 10,
     CON: 10,
     INT: 10,
     WIS: 10,
     CHA: 10
   }
   const [abilityScores, setAbilityScores] = useState(defaultScores);
   const modifier = useMemo(() => (abilityScores.STR - 10) / 2, [abilityScores]);
   const helperText = useMemo(
      () => modifier >= 0 ? "+" + modifier : "-" + modifier,
   [modifier]);

   const handleScoreChange = (event) => setAbilityScores(event.target.value);

   return (
      <TextField 
         helperText={helperText}
         // other props
      />
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using front-end frameworks like React, at least in the context of DOM changes, is to avoid things like `document.getElementById....`

What you need is one more state variable.

```
const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState("");
```

And then in your `handleScoreChange`

```
const handleScoreChange = (event) => {
  const { ability, score } = event.target;
  setAbilityScores({
    ...abilityScores,
    [ability]: score,
  });
  const modifier = (abilityScores.STR - 10) / 2;
  setHelperText(modifier >= 0 ? "+" + modifier : "-" + modifier)
};
```

Finally in your `TextField`

```
<TextField helperText={helperText} {... other attributes} />
```